# Any idea why my variables won't print?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, indexing

I know why these types of errors generally occur, but in my situation, I can't figure out why.

Here's what I'm trying to do: First of all, the type of file I'm working with is a spreadsheet that contains integers and strings, or combinations of both in a given cell.

Now, I have previously written a program that will allow me to append and make a list of all values from a given column on this spreadsheet, and all the values look something like this "c.2232_2234A>G" or "c.23C>T" (these are the types of values that the variables 'mutation' and 'mutation_list' contain. So, for each value in my list, I want to cross-reference it with all other values in my list and find possible matches, and then if they match, then I want to append certain info from a different column of the spreadsheet and print it, and so on.

Edit: I just changed it so that I am comparing the same list against itself. So in this given list, for a particular mutation, I want it to cross-reference it with all other mutations in the list and append the family number and other variables (listed below) for those matches. Although now I don't get the index error, I don't get an output in terms of the variables that I listed. Any ideas?

Here's what I have so far:

```
for y in range(1, len(mutation)):
      for z in range(1,len(mutation):
            if mutation[y] == mutation[z]:
                  print "Family Number", family_num[z], "\t", "Result", result[z], "\t", "Mutation", mutation[y], "\t", "Site", site[z]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? We don't know which list throws the error.

Comment: Are you sure the length of `family_num`, `result`, `mutation` and `site` are the expected?

Comment: It is off that you are processing starting with 1 since python lists start at 0. Since you are using y & z based on len(mutation) and len(mutation_list) respectively, it is much more likely that your index problems come from references to family_num[z], result[z] or site[z]

Comment: Did you start by printing some index info?

Comment: By the way, consider using `z = mutation_list.index(mutation[y])`

Comment: @Christian Hey, I'm not sure what you mean by the 'length' of family_num, result, etc..

Comment: Consider using a dictionary from mutations to tuples of mutation-related information instead of the `mutation_list`, `family_num`, `result`, and `site` lists. It'd simplify lookup and make things a lot quicker if their are a lot of different mutation types.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ the length of the 'mutation' list is around 554 and the length of the 'mutation_list' is around 1700. However, that shouldn't be the problem right?

Comment: @user2357112 Hey, can you show me an example code on how to do that using the same variables that I used? I'm horrible at using dictionaries in the context that you mentioned it and I think it would benefit me here.

Comment: @bioprogrammer I mean, print the index variables along with the list lengths. If you have e.g. index == length it's because you forgot to use 0-indexing (0 to length-1). Either way it's often useful information

Comment: @bioprogrammer, it would be a lot easier for us to help you if you post the **error stack trace**.

Comment: @GaryWalker I tried to replace the entire print statement wiht just "Yes" and I still get the same error, so it doesn't appear that my list index problem comes from those references.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, it should work. Maybe the problem is not in that `for` loop, but is somewhere else. Please, would you mind posting the **error stack trace**?

Comment: Just in case you don't know, the **error stack trace** (or *traceback*) is what python spits out to let you know an error occured.  If you look at the beginning of it, it says "Traceback".  It also tells what line number in what file the error occurred in, as well as the error type.  It gives a *wealth* of information, and debugging is often as simple as reading and understanding the traceback.  This is why you are asked to post it... it can take 10 seconds to solve what could take an hour without it.

Comment: @Christian I don't have the error stack trace because I'm not getting an error, the program is printing out the text I have written in quotations, but not the actual values i.e. it prints "Family Number", but doesn't print the value for that

Comment: Mmmm, then could you post all the **output** you get?

Comment: @Christian The problem is this, sorry for not stating it clearly earlier: I am getting values and output near the beginning, but after a while, the program just seems to run forever (unless I interrupt it) with just the print statements like "Family number", "Results", etc, without any values following them like it's supposed to. This shouldn't be happening. So I can't really paste it since the program just goes on infinitely. Any ideas ?

Comment: Your program won't run infinitely in the code you posted. The issue may be in another part of the program. A suggestion: put some `print` statements along the program, and see where it get's stucked.

Comment: @Christian I just noticed one problem that may not explain why it runs infinitely but definitely with my output. The way I have written it, for each mutation, it will compare against all others in the list and find matches, but then once it goes to those mutations, it will cross-reference with the mutations that it has already been cross-referenced to, and show redundant results. You know what I mean?

Comment: Yes and I thought about a way to solve it. But I strongly recommend you to go step by step. First fix the issue you are having right now. Then, take a look to other problems.

Comment: @Christian I got python to just output the program into a txt file and it turns out that it wasn't infinite, but over a million iterations of the loop, although I only have 1700 rows in the data set that I'm using, so I think it may be a function of the problem I just mentioned. I can't think of how to solve it, can you shed some light?

Comment: Since this is another problem, please make another post describing it more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

In the print statement, concatenate the list, variables, whatever, to string. Try that?

```
for y in range(1, len(mutation)):
      for z in range(1,len(mutation):
            if mutation[y] == mutation[z]:
                  print("Family Number", str(family_num[z]), "\t", "Result", str(result[z]), "\t", "Mutation", str(mutation[y]), "\t", "Site", str(site[z]))
```